# User gets logged in but still shows error message in magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, error, customer-account, login

My customer gets logged in successfully into their account but still magento shows error message.
https://nimb.ws/GicM2b
How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

From the login page , somehow your code reaches to this controller page (file: /vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/LoginPost.php), here you will see that message , then you can edit here or in your custom module. 
**Edit**
I checked your case , so in your case this file will be present in your custom module, override is given already by you , you need to recognize/ find your modified controller file, it will be very similar to above mentioned file and you can further edit that custom controller file. 
Edit 2 - Image is added for your reference 
[image]
Thanks
Vibhore

Comment: Why that message is coming? Customer is successfully logged in. I dont want to show that message

Comment: Once you reach the correct file , then you can modify the php code and need not to display that according to your programming conditions.